# Display 4 tabs in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css

we created 2 tabs using below code [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , I need to create 2 more tabs. i want like below image :

[image]

```js
window.changeTab = function(tabNum){
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
        for(i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tablinks[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
        tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-text");
        for(i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tabs[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.tabs{
        display:inline-block;
        width:250px;
        height:45px;
        line-height:45px;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:orange;
        color:white;
        font-size:19px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabs:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .tabs.active{
        cursor:default;
    }
    .tabs.active:hover{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .tab-text{
        display:none;
        width:90%;
        height:auto;
        padding:5%;
    }
    .tab-text.active{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tab-container">
    <div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-text active">
        INSERT FIRST TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-text">
        INSERT SECOND TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

what i want is to display 4 tabs in single row.

so that if i click on tab, it should open related information.

Please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you declaring your variables with `var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be what your looking for?

```js
window.changeTab = function(tabNum){
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
        for(i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tablinks[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
        tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-text");
        for(i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tabs[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.tabs{
        display:inline-block;
        width:25%;
        float:left;
        height:45px;
        line-height:45px;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:orange;
        color:white;
        font-size:19px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabs:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .tabs.active{
        cursor:default;
    }
    .tabs.active:hover{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .tab-text{
        display:none;
        width:90%;
        height:auto;
        padding:5%;
    }
    .tab-text.active{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tab-container">
    <div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(2)">Third</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(3)">Fourth</div>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-text active">
        INSERT FIRST TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-text">
        INSERT SECOND TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-text">
        INSERT THIRD TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-text">
        INSERT FOURTH TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 4th tab content is not displaying, please update answer.

Comment: i updated your code [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) first tab is starting after some space.

can you please help me to display the first tab from left. and all tabs should display in single row.

Comment: `<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs"></div>` this is your issue where you have `space tabs` at the end its creating another tab I'm pretty sure; update your code and let me know if this fixed it.

Comment: this is complete `div` code , can you please tell me which is space tab and what code i need to remove here : http://pasted.co/7f4b1d9b

Comment: replace `<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">` with `<div class="product-collateral toggle-content">`

Comment: nice, can you please help me to display horizontal lines between the tabs , also vertical line below and above as here : http://prnt.sc/boyj3b

Comment: If i have answered your question correctly please mark my answer as the correct answer thankyou.

Comment: Thansk for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can add css rule like :

```
.tabs {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

or else you can use BS classes col-sm-3.

Comment: i want to display both tabs and contents under those tabs

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe Are you looking for tabs within tabs? if yes edit your question

Comment: @SanjeevK no ,  i want 4 tabs in row. as like other answer.

Comment: adding css rule should work than. The tab-content i.e tab-container are not displayed within tabs, so i dont think that should be an issue.

Comment: Thansk for your support.

Comment: can you please help me to display horizontal lines between the tabs , also vertical line below and above as here : http://prnt.sc/boyj3b in this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```js
window.changeTab = function(tabNum){
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
        for(i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tablinks[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
        tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-text");
        for(i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tabs[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.tabs{
        display:table-cell;
        height:45px;
        line-height:45px;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:orange;
        color:white;
        font-size:19px;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .tabs:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .tabs.active{
        cursor:default;
    }
    .tabs.active:hover{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .tab-nav{
        display:table;
    }
    .tab-text{
        display:none;
        width:90%;
        height:auto;
        padding:5%;
    }
    .tab-text.active{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tab-nav">
    <div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(2)">Tags</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(3)">Reviews</div>
</div>
<div id="tab-container">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-text active">
        INSERT FIRST TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-text">
        INSERT SECOND TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-text">
        INSERT THIRD TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-text">
        INSERT FOURTH TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk for your support. as other user posted the answer first , i accepted that answer.

Comment: can you please help me to display horizontal lines between the tabs , also vertical line below and above as here : http://prnt.sc/boyj3b in this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)